# RubyOnRails Internal API Call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, serialization

I am completely new to RubyOnRails so please be careful for even simplest mistakes I could have done. I developed a simple app that displayes some data from a .csv file. Here my code:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

 def index
  @users = getUsers
 end

 private def getUsers
  invoker = ProviderInvoker.new(UserProvider.new("app/data/user_data.csv"))
  invoker.getData
 end
end
```

My app displaying the data as I wanted. No problem so far but I want to create and use an internal API for providing data so I am changing my UsersController into this:

```
require "net/http"

class UsersController < ApplicationController

 def index
   uri = URI("http://localhost:3000/api/users")
   response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
   @users = JSON.parse(response)
 end
end
```

and created another UsersController under app/controllers/api

```
class Api::UsersController < ApplicationController

 def index
  invoker = ProviderInvoker.new(UserProvider.new("app/data/user_data.csv"))
  data = invoker.getData
  render json: data 
 end
end
```

And lastly I created a serializer under app/serializers:

```
class UsersSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :user_name
end
```

When I go to my index page I get an error like

> No serializer found for resource: #< User:0x07aaebb0 @id="1", @first_name="Susan", @last_name="Gomez", @email="sgomez0@cpanel. net", @user_name="sgomez0">

Obviously there is something wrong with my serializer but I can't manage to find what.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to put serializer under `Api` module also, so you won't be confused which serializer you use.
As a try you may set serializer manually in controller, like this:

```rb
 def index
  invoker = ProviderInvoker.new(UserProvider.new("app/data/user_data.csv"))
  data = invoker.getData
  render json: data, each_serializer: UsersSerializer, adapter: :json
 end
```

Comment: Thank you for replay ! I think this did the trick then I get an error like 'NoMethodError (undefined method `model_name' for User:Class)' right after this. I made a quick googling and add an ActiveRecord::Base inheritance to User model but now I am getting an error like 'ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Could not find table 'users'):'. I don't have a db table for users, I developed user class myself, not generated it via console. I am not going to use any database transactions, do I have to generate a database just for using an API ? Doesnt make sense.

Comment: No, I guess you can avoid using model and database, but in this case I am not sure that you can use serializer. Why not just simply receive json and display it in view as it is? With handling its keys in the view template

Comment: Yes I don't have to use a serializer but how can I receive it without getting "No serializer found for resource: .." error I mentioned in my question ?